# How to fix apache server in uWamp

Tags: apache, uwamp

I use uWamp for a long time on Windows Vista, 7 and 10 but it don't work on my new computer (Dell XPS with core i7 10th gen) : Apache don't Go.

The port 80 is used by "system" so y change it many times without effect.

I install Wamp and I have no problem when I use port 81.

What happens with uWamp?

Answer (score 0):

check, download & install version 32bits
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

works for me on win 7 64bits

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall or Disable SKYPE in Windows 10 - some new builds have it running by default which uses port 80